# How to have two versions of PHP on the same website on different ports

Tags: php-7, iis-8, php-5.6

I'm in the middle of migrating from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.x.

Locally I have a copy of the website and as I make changes, I want to be able to test it using the current version and version 7 of PHP.

I know I can change the settings each time or have a separate copy of the website, but that is getting tiresome, so wondered if it is possible to use the same scripts for both versions but just change the port number on the url to switch between the two.

Having two versions of fastcgi does not seem to take on the same site.  Is there a way to do this or do I have to stick to the tiresome approach?